# Displaying Page numbers from HTML in TCPDF

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I am writing HTML to  PDF from TCPDF using

```
$pdfobject->writeHTML($PrintingFile, true, false, true, false, '');
```

I want to add the Page numbers on all the Pages.

If I use `$pdf->Footer($pdfobject)` it prints the page number only on the last page. Can you please help me how can I print the page numbers on All pages ?

Answer (score 1):

you can put this on top or footer of your page

```
$pdf->writeHtmlCell($widhheader,3,20,4,'<p>Page '.$pdf->getAliasNumPage().' of  '.' '.$pdf->getAliasNbPages().'</p>','',1,0,false,'R');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help... But does not prints the page on every page

Comment: can you provide the code, I mean full code?
are you set to create the page as static or as dynamic?
It's important for place the codding

Comment: you can place this code after `$pdf->AddPage();`
if all your pages are created using this syntax then try to put below `$pdf->AddPage();`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are calling the Footer() method before adding any pages.

I found i was adding the footer content after the pages had been generated. It needs to be done before any pages are added

If you use a custom Footer method in your own MyTCPDF class. Ensure the value is set before calling any AddPage calls